# Cannot import python-social-auth into Google App Engine's django project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have python-social-auth installed via pip

```
>>> import social
>>> print social
<module 'social' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/__init__.pyc'>
```

When I tried to run my django project, it complains that there is no module named social

```
File "/media/PROJECT/project/BINGO/bingo/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named social.apps.django_app.default
```

Dropping the module inside my project folder to be used locally, it works:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.getcwd()
/media/PROJECT/project/BINGO/bingo
>>> import social
>>> print social
<module 'social' from 'social/__init__.pyc'>
```

However, now its dependencies can't be found

```
File "/media/PROJECT/project/BINGO/bingo/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py", line 2, in <module> 
   import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

I do have six installed globally. If I use six locally, another dependency, `openid`, then can't be found. I guess I can still keep going and adding all dependencies locally but why aren't my global modules imported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to read the doc's on appengine and it's sandbox.  Everything (modules/libs) not directly provided by the sdk must be included in your project.  All of these must be deployed with your code.

So you can't use the globally installed modules and their dependencies. It all needs to be present (installed or linked) in your project.

I use virtualenv --no-site-packages to install all modules and their dependencies, then symlink these bits from the local site-packages into a lib dir in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I only found the openid and six dependencies.  Actually, couldn't get the six.py to install globally for some reason, so just dumped a copy into each required directory.
Also, ran into an issue with basestring conversion if PY2 which then lead to the default import json silently failing, so had to swap to 'simplejson'.  But in the end, got it working.