# python boilerpipe with google appengine getting import error?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, python-import, boilerpipe

I am trying work out python boilerpipe with google app engine. I have installed boilerpipe and its working fine in my local machine.

boilerpipe installed using `pip`

```
pip install boilerpipe
```

[github link](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe)

sample program works fine with given url

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
extractor = Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', url=your_url)
print(extractor.getText())
```

**Trial 1:**

but the same code when I run with google_appengine generates `ImportError`

**Trial 2**

then after some research I copied modules from `dist_packages` to project directory.
Now I am getting `_jpype module not found`

**Trial 3**

This time I downloaded the packages and trying to build and install in project directory.
boilerpipe installed without error. but jpype giving error `jni.h no such file or directory`

How could I resolve import error? 
Whats the problem with google_appengine while the same code is working properly in local machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot import python-social-auth into Google App Engine's django project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529335/cannot-import-python-social-auth-into-google-app-engines-django-project)

Comment: I originally voted to close this as it was about how to import 3rd party libs - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529335/cannot-import-python-social-auth-into-google-app-engines-django-project/19530847#19530847  for how to do that.  But the question has now become about _jpype.  WHich you can't use on appengine under python.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use libraries that have arbitrary dependancies on 'c' code or that create subprocesses.

Please see documentation on the python appengine sandbox to understand the limitations.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox